# How to get borders/box around a range in Excel using EPPlus in C#

Tags: c#, excel, range, border, epplus

Below code generates borders for all cells within the range[2, 2, 5, 11], but I want only border around the range like a box.

```
var FirstTableRange = wsMyWorkSheet.Cells[2, 2, 5, 11];
FirstTableRange.Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thick;
FirstTableRange.Style.Border.Left.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thick;
FirstTableRange.Style.Border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thick;
FirstTableRange.Style.Border.Bottom.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thick;
```

Answer (score 9):

Below code generates borders around the range specified.

```
 var FirstTableRange = wsMyWorkSheet.Cells[2, 2, 5, 11];
 FirstTableRange.Style.Border.BorderAround(ExcelBorderStyle.Thick);
```

If you write the code as in my question, it will generate borders for each cell within the range[2, 2, 5, 11] but not around the range.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you figured it out yet or not but here is how you put a borders around a range:

`range.Style.Border.BorderAround(OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelBorderStyle.Thick);`

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following line to do this:

```
Range("A1:C10").Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
```

Adapt this to your code above and it should work

**EDIT**: The above code is actually to put a border around every cell in the range and I believe I have misunderstood your question and what you actually want is a border around the range itself.

To do this than use this:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D4").BorderAround _
ColorIndex:=3, Weight:=xlThick
```

This is just an example, change the color to your desired color and thinkness too or just simply keep it as default.

**EDIT**: I have found the following on the internet. Take a look and see if your doing it as the video explains: [Click here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-apply-cell-border-style-in-excel-sheet-using-epplus-net-library-part-t/)

Comment: Actually I am using ExcelPackage in my code, So when I try to adopt your code it says Worksheets doesn't exist in the context.

Comment: @Learner whats the exact error you get? Try adding this to your code where Cells is: `Range("A1:D4").BorderAround _
ColorIndex:=3, Weight:=xlThick`

Comment: I am trying to add your code, but I get, The name 'Worksheets' doesn't exist in the current context. FYI I am using EPPlus reference in my code and creating ExcelPackage then ExcelSheets. But I didn't find any range property for my Worksheet. Ex: wsMyWorkSheet.Range. Help me how to solve my problem.